# Start a GNOME Web (Epiphany) "web application" via command line

Tags: command-line, gnome, epiphany

How do you start a specific web application created by GNOME Web via the command line?

> **Usage example:** The user creates a web application and wants to add that specific web application as a startup program (without opening GNOME Web)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, but it's not very elegant. If you find a better and simpler way to do this, please share.

**Here it is:**

1. Go to:

   > ~/.local/share/applications
2. Open the file with your text editor. It's name will be:

   > epiphany-*yourAppName-RandomAlphanumericalCharacters*.desktop
3. Copy the text following "**Exec=**" (on line 3). It should look like:

   > epiphany --application-mode --profile="/home/*yourusername*/.config/epiphany/app-epiphany-*yourAppName-randomAlphanumericalCharacters*" https://example.com/

Use this command to start the web application.

Comment: is this still accurate for the flatpak version of epiphany? I imagine not